# How to check Platform Version in salesforce

Tags: api, deployment, change-set, release

I want to check platform version of my org. How can i check that.
Actually I'm getting error while deploying change set from sandbox to production like version compatibility check.

I need your support please. reply

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: All components failed Version Compatibility Check.
Every component in this change set requires the "34.0" or higher platform version. Please select an organization with a platform version of "34.0" or higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like your sandbox is on Summer '15 (Api v34) while your production instance is on Spring '15 (Api v33).

In your sandbox, go through all the components and (where possible) set their API version back to 33. This should allow the components to be accepted by the production instance.

Worst case scenario, wait until next week as your production instance will be upgraded to Summer '15 this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of checking the API version is by creating a WSDL file. Jump to **Setup** enter **API** under Develop and select it. Next, click on "Generate Enterprise WSDL". On the next tab, you should see the current API Version of your org instance:

[image]